# A counter example regarding differentiability of a function while a certain limit exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Here's a problem on producing a counter example that I'm having difficulty with. Any help/hint would be much appreciated. Thank you.

> **The Problem :** To produce a function $f$ for which the following limit exists
>   $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$
>   But $f$ is *NOT* differentiable at $x$. $($i.e. we are trying to contradict the *false* converse to the *correct* statement that if $f$ is differentiable at $x,$ then the said limit exists and is equal to $f'(x),$ by producing a counter example$)$.

On a general note, producing counter examples is one of my weaknesses. Do you just remember counter examples or there are ways to actually *construct* them using logical steps? Any general tips would also be much appreciated.

Comment: If $f(x+h)=f(x-h)$ for each $h$ then the limit certainly exists.

Comment: Ah. That was easy. So $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=|x|;~x \in \mathbb{R}$ works $($at $x=0)$! Thanks!

Comment: Why even make $f$ continuous at $0$? Actually, the indicator function fo $\Bbb Q$ is nowhere continuous, but the limit of the OP exists for all $x\in\Bbb Q$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is a nice example! Thanks.